# How to call node function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I am using NodeJS to send emails. Here is my emailer.js file:

```
function email_sender() {
console.log("sending email")
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.company.com',
    port: 25,
    domain: '*.company.com',
    secure: false
});



var mailOptions = {
    from: 'abc@company.com',
    to: 'abc@company.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email',
    html: '<h1>Welcome</h1><p>That was easy!</p>'
};



transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
}
email_sender()
```

This works fine when i use "node emailer.js" in the terminal. However, I have a webpage made in just HTML, JQuery js. In that HTML, I have a button that I use for sending email:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="email_sender()">Send Email</button>
```

How can I call the nodeJS function directly from HTML? I have not worked with Node JS in past and couldnt use javascript email sender (smtp.js) function as its not working using that.

Comment: You cannot call it directly.  You have to make a web request to an endpoint, that then performs the logic.

Comment: This might help https://www.emailjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to create a HTTP server. Here is a simplified example.

Let me show you an example and I can explain the basics:

index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

// Parse URL-encoded bodies when sent by HTML forms
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// Parse JSON bodies when sent by clients
app.use(express.json());

// Return page with form
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile('absolutePathToYour/htmlPage.html');
});

// Process form submit
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.user.name);
  console.log(req.body.user.email);
  function_that_do_something(req.body.user.name, req.body.user.email);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

HTML Form in htmlPage.html:

```html
<form method="post" action="/submit">
    <input type="text" name="user[name]">
    <input type="text" name="user[email]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This server will be listening to the port 8080. When run locally, you can run it by using `http://localhost:8080`.

When the user goes to the root of your website `/`, your server will return the html page with the form in it.

Then, when your form calls the URL `/submit` and send the information, you read the body of the request for the information and send it to your function.

A few things in consideration.

- You should validate the input that you are receiving from the form in order to prevent an attack.
- You should introduce a captcha to prevent a bot to abuse your system.
- There are other packages apart of `express` that might be easier for you to utilize.
- There are many validation and captcha packages for nodejs. Find the one that is most used.
- Remember to add the packages your project use in the `package.json`

Comment: Can I use this even if I already have a HTML File with bunch of other stuff?

Comment: @VaibhavChadha yes. Just send the HTML file to the client, when the client calls the URL. Make sure that your HTML file, whatever code you have there, is calling to the right URL when sending information as GET or POST. Take a look to the `express` package documentation. While your code is in JavaScript for NodeJS, you shouldn't have problems.

Comment: Umm... @acarlstein I think you meant to type ``app.post('/submit')`` instead of ``app.get('/submit')``.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Take-Some-Bytes I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot install and use packages via npm in a normal html website. The solution would be to check if a "nodemailer" CDN exists and use it in your script tag in your html file so that the nodemailer's function would be available globally. Or you can also download the nodemailer.js (nodemailer.min.js) file if exists and use it in your project folder and import it via script tags in your html file

Comment: Keeping in mind that exposing email logic on the client side also runs the risk of exposing such logic to web bots.